# Meteor - Using reactive variables in anonymous functions

Tags: meteor

How can I use reactive template variables (from Template.data) in an anonymous function within the template rendered function? (I want to keep it reactive).

```
Template.templateName.rendered = function() {
    function testFunction(){
        //Log the field 'title' associated with the current template
        console.log(this.data.title);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was simple using autorun() AND using Template.currentData() to grab the values from within autorun():

```
let title;

Template.templateName.rendered = function() {
   this.autorun(function(){
        title = Template.currentData().title;
   });

    function testFunction(){
        console.log(title);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do (like printing `this.data.title` whenever it changes?), but you should:

1. use a [Reactive variable](http://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html) (add `reactive-var` package, then create a `var myVar = new ReactiveVar()`
2. If necessary, wrap your function with [`Tracker.autorun`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun) (or [`this.autorun`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-autorun) in a template creation / rendered event).

So you could have like:

Parent template HTML:

```spacebars
<template name="parentTemplateName">
  {{> templateName title=myReactiveVar}}
</template>
```

Parent template JS:

```js
Template.parentTemplateName.helpers({
  myReactiveVar: function () {
    return new ReactiveVar("My Title!");
  }
});
```

Template JS:

```js
Template.templateName.onRendered(function() {
  // Re-run whenever a ReactiveVar in the function block changes.
  this.autorun(function () {
    //Print the field 'title' associated with the current template
    console.log(getValue(this.data.title));
  });
});

function getValue(variable) {
  return (variable instanceof ReactiveVar) ? variable.get() : variable;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the title field from the Template.data in the anonymous function, and to keep it reactive. I don't need to print it on the page, so no helper needed. Updating my question to make this more clear now. Thanks!

Comment: You know that the data context (i.e. `template.data`) is [non-reactive](http://docs.meteor.com/api/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-data) by default. That is why I showed above that you have to explicitly use a `ReactiveVar`. That is why I used a helper, but only to call it. You can create your data context however you like.

Comment: FYI using 'this' in autorun does not seem to refer to Template. I had to use Template.currentData() to get the data from within autorun.

Comment: @jetlej thank you for the feedback, indeed I overlooked that part as it is just an adaptation of your code. Not sure I will spend energy to help you next time though.

Answer (score -1):

```
Template.templateName.onRendered(function(){
   console.log(this.data.title);
});
```

Comment: The point is for the variable to be available in the anonymous function *within* the onRender function